# Delete all rows where value in a column does not match value in column in another dataset

Tags: r

I have two datasets (imported as dataframes). The first dataframe is a list of chromosomes and positions of interest along that chromosome (Number, Qual and dt are just other columns). The dataframe is called sam

```
  Number   Qual  chr     leftPos     dt
   3        0   chr1    4105086     255
   4       16   chr1    4464364     255
   5       16   chr1    4464390     255
   6       16   chr1    9655049     255
   7       16   chr1    9945004     255
   etc
```

The second data set (called counts) contains chromosomes and positions along that chromosome that I am interested in:

```
    Chr     Locus
   chr1    4105086
   chr1    4464364
```

I would like to erase all rows in sam that do not have a corresponding combination of Chr and Locus in counts.

The output should look like:

```
Number   Qual  chr     leftPos     dt
3         0   chr1     4105086      255
4        16   chr1     4464364      255
```

I dont want to merge because I dont want extra columns etc in the original dataset (sam) I just want to exclude rows based on the first dataset.

Comment: Not very clear, but I guess you should take a look at `?merge`.

Comment: how do you merge when the columns you want to merge on are called different things?

Comment: See the `by.x` and `by.y` arguments of `merge`.

Comment: OK but that doesnt work when you want to merge on the basis of two column names in each dataframe, which are named differently

Comment: Still not clear. Please, provide a sample of the `counts` data.frame and what you want as desired result.

Comment: Couldn't you just `sam[sam$leftPos %in% counts$Locus, ]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for

```
# sample data
sam = structure(list(Number = 3:7, Qual = c(0L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), 
    chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr1", class = "factor"), 
    leftPos = c(4105086L, 4464364L, 4464390L, 9655049L, 9945004L
    ), dt = c(255L, 255L, 255L, 255L, 255L)), .Names = c("Number", 
"Qual", "chr", "leftPos", "dt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

counts = structure(list(Chr = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "chr1", class = "factor"), 
    Locus = c(4105086L, 4464364L)), .Names = c("Chr", "Locus"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

library(dplyr)
new_data = sam %>% filter(paste0(chr,"_",leftPos) %in%
                            with(counts, paste0(Chr,"_",Locus)))
new_data
#   Number Qual  chr leftPos  dt
# 1      3    0 chr1 4105086 255
# 2      4   16 chr1 4464364 255
```

Or use merge as suggested

```
new_data = merge(sam, counts, by.x=c("chr","leftPos"), by.y=c("Chr","Locus"))
new_data = new_data[,c(3,4,1,2,5)]
#   Number Qual  chr leftPos  dt
# 1      3    0 chr1 4105086 255
# 2      4   16 chr1 4464364 255
```

Comment: OK can't use merge as that alters the original dataset which I dont want to do. Dumb question but how do you output the dplyr answer to a new dataframe?

Comment: @user3632206, See edit. Actually you could re-arrange the columns after merging.

Comment: OK so I would far prefer the dplyr route as it only filters rather than alters the data. However, it doesn't seem to be filtering the data- there is no error message but it doesnt seem to be filtering. The merge route does filter but all the column rearrangements that have to then happen make the code bulky.